# How do I maximize the loot from a treasure Goblin?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the Treasure Goblins work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/how-do-the-treasure-goblins-work)

Treasure Goblins are feisty little monsters that drop gold trails as you chase them around, and explode in a giant explosion of coins and loot when you finally bring them down.

Is the gold the goblin drops while fleeing separate from their "on-death" spoils, or does it get drawn from the same pool? If I want the most gold from the Goblin, should I kill them immediately, or wait for them to litter the ground with gold a bit, first?

[How do the Treasure Goblins work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/how-do-the-treasure-goblins-work) explains *what* they are, and their general behavior, but I know that already; I'm more interested in the strategy that milks the most coins from their grubby little paws. Should I obliterate them ASAP? Or should I let them leave a trail of coins for as long as possible before offing them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly what OrigamiRobot is after with his question as well -  note his addendum at the end -  and is why he hasn't accepted the answer he's currently received. Just because the dupe is unanswered, doesn't make it not a dupe. :P