# Treasure goblin's portal

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the Treasure Goblins work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/how-do-the-treasure-goblins-work)

Is there a way to use the treasure goblin's portal and travel where he is going? There must be more gold where it is coming from. Is it at all possible?

Comment: @Blem that question is becoming too bloated for "Here is everything you need to know about treasure goblins".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.  Unfortunately not.**

Your only goal is [or should be] to kill him before he enters the portal with his loot.