# How do I kill the Treasure Goblin in Hell?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been playing through Hell mode on Diablo 3 for the better part of a day and have come across 3 Treasure Goblins. On all the lower difficulties you can either stun or disorientate him to cancel the portal. I've tried doing everything I can to stop him on Hell mode, though, and he still travels through. Is there a way, apart from blowing him up and killing him before he teleports, to stop Treasure Goblins from teleporting away?

Comment: My guess is that the whole point is that you have to kill him really fast in hell mode (or higher difficulties)

Comment: The Treasure Goblin can't be interrupted in any game mode. At the lower difficulties, he simply dies faster. As soon as the portal comes up, you have a set amount of time to kill him.

Comment: @Domocus Not sure. In one game, my team was able to somehow cancel the portal and the goblin ran elsewhere and started a new portal.

Comment: @Domocus I've also cancelled the goblin's portal on Normal before. I can't remember exactly how, but I know my Monk is very fond of Cyclone Strike, which is a skill that pulls all nearby enemies to me, so that could have been what cancelled it.

Comment: @Domocus I have as well canceled his portal.  I am a wizard and used 3 arcane orbs (that each hit) which canceled his portal.

Comment: Any info about closing the portal would be appreciated [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/how-do-the-treasure-goblins-work)

Comment: Hm...ive attempted every form of CC known to a monk and yet never cancels

Comment: My monk cancels portals on _every_ hit; I'm not sure which skill/item/??? is causing it

Comment: @Nevir As stated before in a previous comment, there have been times where you can cancel the portal, im pointing out that you cant anymore in hell difficulty.

Comment: Fists of Thunder does a short knockback on every finishing move (3rd hit).  That and Lashing Tail Kick can both interrupt treasure bandits pre-hell.

Answer (score 10):

For information on [Treasure Goblins, take a look at this previously asked question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/how-do-the-treasure-goblins-work).

*From my testing*, there is no other way to effectively close the portal besides interrupting the cast and/or destroying the treasure goblin.  In Hell mode, all enemies have increased resistance and increased HP.  Therefore, you **HAVE** to output more DPS to prevent him from getting away.

From what I have noticed, once his portal is down, you have a set amount of time to kill him or make him *run away* from the portal before it doesn't matter: He will get into the portal and your loot is gone.

**A few recommendations:**

- Try cornering him.  This will obviously try to prevent him from running away and allow you (and your team if applicable) to dump all of your DPS in a concentrated area.
- If you have a mercenary or other teammate(s) with you, attack him from both sides - in attempt to not allow the treasure goblin from running away.
- If you have not attacked the treasure goblin yet, **DON'T ATTACK HIM UNTIL YOU CLEAR THE SURROUNDING AREA**.  He will only run away once you start attacking him and if he, you, or any of your teammates aggro more enemies on the harder difficulties - it will get harder -practically exponentially per enemy - to take him down before he gets away.
- Lastly, and obviously, make the treasure goblin your party's main priority [if applicable].  Notify everyone in your party that you see a treasure goblin and wait until everyone is ready to take him down (and the area surrounding him is clear).

Comment: I'd like to point out that the Treasure Goblin does seem to have a counter of some sort that will cause him to create a teleport if you have not damaged him. I've seen this happen several times when clearing out the surrounding area.

Answer (score 1):

The goblin will open a portal if either of these two occur:

1. He gets far enough away
2. A set time has passed

If it's the former, you can cancel the portal; if it's the latter, you can't.