# Can Treasure Goblins drop legendary items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have never seen a legendary item drop from a treasure goblin, and am beginning to wonder if it's even possible for them to drop one.

Can Treasure Goblins drop legendary items? And does the type of Treasure Goblin matter?

I have read [How do the Treasure Goblins work](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66349/8462), however it does not address this question at all in either the question or the answers provided.

Comment: yes, they do. I've had a few legendaries from them. But I can't say anything about their types, so would keep it as a comment

Answer (score 4):

Legendary items can be dropped by basically everything that's killable, lootable or that has a red border when moving your cursor over it.

Treasure goblin hunting is actually a popular method of farming legendary items alongside with chests and bosses.

As of now there are no 100% reliable statistics of what drop the most legendary items but I asked a friend of mine with paragon 370 (so I kinda think he knows some things when it comes to farming) and he told me that the most legendaries come from things in this order.

- Killing a boss for the first time (100%)
- Small chests
- Goblins (any type) = Big chests
- Lootable corpses/Destroyable objects (with red borders)
- Regular monsters = Killing a boss for the nth time
- Elite packs (yellow and blue) = Elite bosses

I myself haven't played as much as my friend did but i can say that I see a very similar drop rate when I'm playing.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful to know however I am wondering specifically if treasure goblins have an increased chance to drop legendary items just because they are treasure goblins, and if their type/color affects that chance or not. I realize every single creature in the game does have some small base chance to drop a legendary :)