# Is it more profitable to let the new goblin types live longer?

Tags: diablo-iii

The new 2.1.2 patch introduces additional types of goblins to Adventure Mode. 
These goblins include;

- A green one for crafting materials and plans.
- A red one for blood shards.
- A silver one for gems.

[image: Picture of New Goblins]

Now the previous standard goblin would consistently drop small amounts of gold when chased, and when slain he would explode in a shower of gold and loot of various kinds. The gold he dropped when being chased and struck was never any amount of note however, usually 1-5 gold every few steps.

My question is, since these new goblins drop items of their respective kind when struck rather than gold, is it more profitable to deliberately chase them for some time before killing them or would it be best to kill them as soon as possible, or does it not matter at all? (For the purpose of acquiring additional crafting materials, blood shards, or gems)

Comment: This question I just found may be considered a duplicate, only that question only addresses the original treasure goblin and mine addresses the new ones, I'll let the community decide as they see fit

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/how-do-the-treasure-goblins-work?rq=1

Comment: I havent tested this but it should have the same ideal as letting a normal goblin live.

Comment: I suggested an edit to the title. I do not believe this is a duplicate to the other question as it raises a new and basically unique angle. I am also interested in the answer :)

Comment: @TravisJ I cannot see your suggested edit, and there is no edit history, so it must have been rejected by others, what was your suggestion?

Comment: The [rejected edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/115711).  In general, you can find a rejected edit by going to the person's profile, selecting the activity tab, and then clicking on suggestions.

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you for the suggested title change, I've combined our two ideas into one better title.

Comment: I ran into a whole bunch of these yesterday, but like 10 minimum, so just tried to kill them all without them getting away. Regardless, was wondering the same thing, could really use some more gems.

Answer (score 3):

Overall I would say no, it is not worth it to keep them alive. What they drop while running away compared when they die is so small that it isn't worth the trouble. Especially since when they run, they could run into a larger pack of monsters or worse, elite packs, that could keep you from getting to the goblin in time to kill it.

I'm not sure how or if difficulty affects the Blood Thief and how many Blood Shards it drops. On Torment 6 I usually get around 200-250, so the single shards it drops while running are so comparatively small.

The only exception I *would* add is the Gem Hoarder, but only if you're really hurting for gems and can reliably kill it just before it leaves through it's portal.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a viable technique, but for me personally I think it's pointless to let the ***Odious Collector*** (the crafting materials goblin) or the ***Gem Hoarder*** (the gems goblin) live for long, as they drop items that are quite common from regular mobs too.

I would however try to delay the death of the ***Blood Thief*** (the blood shards goblin), as blood shards aren't regularly dropped from monsters and you have to complete a bounty or rift to get a decent amount of them, so having the goblin drop even small amounts of blood shards before it dies can still contribute to farming.