# When chasing treasure goblins, should I leave them living as long as possible, if I can control it?

Tags: diablo-iii

When hunting down treasure goblins, like the [Fate Peddler](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Thief), it drops items periodically.

If I leave it living, just ensure I damage it enough once it tries to escape through a portal, will my net reward from such a goblin be affected?

Meaning, does each such goblin have a fixed amount of reward to drop, or does it have some like that + that periodic drop?

If the latter, then perhaps the longer I can keep it living but keep it from escaping, the higher my total reward would be?

Comment: Did you mean diablo 3 or diablo for the tags?

Comment: Sorry, I chose the wrong tag.

Comment: All good I gotchu!  Thought it was weird that you posted a diablo 3 quesiton like an hour ago and then a diablo 1 question.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/how-do-the-treasure-goblins-work

Comment: If I remember correctly, the longer they continue to live, the harder it will be to stop them in time. Eventually they will stop being interrupted and if you don't kill them then, they will escape.